# Merging Two Anchor Points in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a shape path that contains two shapes within it. I want to merge two anchor points from - note that the two anchors are on different paths on the same shape. Here is an image.

[image: Screenshot]

Is it possible?

Comment: In the sense transforming these two anchor points into one anchor point with four paths going out from it, no that's not possible. An anchor point can have no more than two paths going out from it.

Comment: What about merging the two shape paths within the shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the general case, the normal way is to make sure the path segments/shapes overlap slightly, set `Path operations` (at the top when the path Direct Selection (black arrow) tool is selected) to `Combine Shapes`, then `Merge Shape Components` with the overlapping paths selected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got to the solution of my problem a different way.

I was tracing an image that contained a lot of intricate points and I was using the default shapes in Photoshop to aid me (circle and triangle). As a result my shape contained a lot of different paths.

After I finished tracing the object, I converted the shape into a custom shape which gave me a nice outline, as opposed to hundreds of different paths.